# С чего начать нахождение корней данного уравнения q^10 - 21q + 20 = 0

Tags: математика, численные-методы

Уравнение выведено из формулы суммы элем. геом. прогрессии S = b1 (1 - q^n) / (1 - q), где b1 = 10, n = 10, S = 210. Необходимо найти знаменатель прогрессии, собственно q.

Comment: Как я понимаю, очевидный корень `q=1` не годится? тогда только численными методами получить примерно 1.1569...

Comment: Да, забыл сказать n = 10, т.е. 10 элементов прогрессии. Если, q = 1 => S = 0, тогда сумма равна нулю. q = 1 не подходит. Ресурс wolframalpha выдает ответ 1.1569 - верно. Но мне нужен ход решения для моей программы.

Comment: Как вы решили что "q = 1 => S = 0"? Это не верно. Десять членов по `21` в сумме дают `S = 210`.

Comment: Да любым методом. Ньютона, хорд, деления пополам...

Answer (score 1):

[Так](https://ideone.com/4HDU5G) годится? :)

```
template<floating_point Double, typename Func>
Double binEq(Double left, Double right, Double eps, Func f)
{
    using std::swap;
    Double x = left;
    if (left > right)
    {
        swap(left,right);
    }
    Double fl = f(left), fr = f(right);
    if (fl*fr > 0) throw runtime_error("Wrong range");

    while ( right - left > eps )
    {
        x = (left + right)/Double(2.0);

        (fl * f(x) < 0 ? right : left) = x;
    }

    return x;
}

class Progress
{
    double sum, b1;
    int n;
public:
    double operator()(double q) { return sum*(q-1) - b1*(pow(q,n)-1); }
    Progress(double sum, double b1, int n):sum(sum),b1(b1),n(n){}
};

int main()
{
    cout << setprecision(12) << binEq(1.001,10.0,1e-13,Progress(210,10,10)) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, позже добавлю комментарии, все еще разбираюсь ..

Comment: Это просто поиск корня методом половинного деления. Отвечал на вопрос с этим методом, ну, решил заодно и вам написать :) Язык-то у вас нигде указан не был, ток что я на С++...

Comment: Переписал на javascript.